# Кто объяснит чудное поведение position:fixed в моем случае?

Tags: css3, html, html5, css, вёрстка

Не думал, что спустя столько лет верстки буду задавать подобный вопрос, но не могу себе объяснить логику работы `position:fixed`.
Я не применяю выравнивание с помощью `top/right`, `top/bottom`, `margin` и т.д. Использую `fixed`, как оно есть. При скроллинге больше 500 пикселей на страничке [ipestov.com](http://ipestov.com) присваиваю фиксирование для баннера. Но при разных разрешениях 1280 и, к примеру, 1400 баннер фиксируется в разных местах.
Проверил несколько раз `media queries`, родительские `relative` и т.д.

Почему так происходит?

Ответ пользователю @Etki: Это понятно, но при `static` у меня положение одно и то же.

Comment: Если top/right/bottom/left не указаны явно, то в качестве положения будет использоваться то расположение элемента, которое было бы у него при position: static. Что и меняется за счет наличия или отсутствия верхнего интро-блока.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Блин, ну ей-богу. Ничего так не выводит из себя, как вопрошающий, который в упор не видит твоего ответа.

1920 - расстояние от верхнего края экрана 30 пикселей за счет margin-top у aside

[image]
<sub>(источник: [scaleengine.net](https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/4b20858c812fad174bb7a8920c531e10.png))</sub>

~1300 - расстояние от верхнего края экрана 430 пикселей - 400 интро-блок, 30 все тот же margin-top

[image]
<sub>(источник: [scaleengine.net](https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/be2a2321128632f0bd34cc637645d6b0.png))</sub>

fixed берет и просто влепляется в это место, в одном случае 30px, в другом 430px.

поставьте fixed всегда вне зависимости от скролла - увидите сами.